# If $(a,n)=1$, prove that $ax \equiv b \mod n$ has exactly one solution $t$ such that $0\leq t < n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

Problem:

If $(a,n)=1$, prove that $ax \equiv b \mod n$ has exactly one solution $t$ such that $0\leq t < n$.

My attempt:

I know that $ax - b = nk$ for some integer $k$, so $x$ must be of the form $\frac{nk+b}{a}$ for the equation to hold. To find such an $x$ I started with the fact that $(a,n)=1$. This means that there exists integers $u,v$ (not necessarily unique) such that $au+nv=1$. Now solving for $u$ and multiplying by $b$ gives $bu=\frac{b-bnv}{a}$, which is a solution as it is in the right form.

My problem is that I don't know how to show the $0<bu \leq n$ part. Am I on the right track in how I constructed a solution? Could someone please give me a hint as to what to do next? Thanks!

Comment: Notice that 
\begin{align*}
a(\color{blue}{bu+3n})+n(\color{blue}{bv-3a})&=b\\
a(\color{blue}{bu+2n})+n(\color{blue}{bv-2a})&=b\\
a(\color{blue}{bu+n})+n(\color{blue}{bv-a})&=b\\
a(\color{blue}{bu-n})+n(\color{blue}{bv+a})&=b\\
a(\color{blue}{bu-2n})+n(\color{blue}{bv+2a})&=b\\
a(\color{blue}{bu-3n})+n(\color{blue}{bv+3a})&=b\\
a(\color{blue}{bu-4n})+n(\color{blue}{bv+4a})&=b\\
\end{align*}
And so forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your observation that there exists $u,v$ such that $au+nv=1$. This essentially means that $u$ is a multiplicative inverse of $a$ modulo $n$.

Then,
$aux\equiv ub\pmod n$

$(1-nv)x\equiv ub\pmod n$

$x\equiv ub\pmod n$

You can add and subtract $n$ from $bu$ till it satisfies the range $0\leq t<n$, it will still be a solution of the congruence.

Comment: Ooh gotcha, yeah that makes sense! I hadn't made the connection of thinking of $u$ and $a$ as multiplicative inverses $\mod n$. That is useful, thanks!